# Can we use the verb "adjoin" this way?

Tags: usage

Can we use the verb "adjoin" this way? Adjoin means attach according to the dictionary, but attach can be used in a figurative way, so I was wondering if you could use the word adjoin with non physical things.

For example:

> Here's the document adjoined to the present meeting.

Comment: I wouldn't use _adjoin_ or _attach_ in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Probably not...

As a general rule, **adjoin** means that one thing is connected to the other. You can see this from Google's dictionary:

> be next to and joined with (a building, room, or piece of land).

You'll notice that they also mention that it should generally be used for *a building, room, or piece of land*.

---

However, an **attachment** is the word you're looking for. This is what it is considered when you put a link in something (attaching a link) or including a document with something (attaching a document). Here's Google's *first* definition of the term:

> fasten; join.

They say, later that it could *also* mean (for your context):

> fasten (a related document) to another, or to an email.

---

**To sum up,** "adjoin" usually means two physical things, but "attach" would be the correct word in this context.